# scrollbar functionality which should load more data on scrolling to the top

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app=angular.module('scroll', ['angular-scroll-complete']).controller("Main",Main)


//app.js
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    var counter = 0;
    var scrollingTop=document.getElementById("fixed");
    //alert("controller"+scrollingTop.offsetHeight)
    scrollingTop.scrollTop=scrollingTop.scrollHeight
   console.log("hi==="+scrollingTop.scrollHeight)
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $scope.items.push({id: counter});
            counter += 10;
        }
       
    };
    $scope.loadMore();
}


//angular-scroll-complete.js
var app=angular.module('scroll', ['angular-scroll-complete']).controller("Main",Main)



function Main($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    var counter = 0;
    var scrollingTop=document.getElementById("fixed");
    //alert("controller"+scrollingTop.offsetHeight)
    scrollingTop.scrollTop=scrollingTop.scrollHeight
   console.log("hi==="+scrollingTop.scrollHeight)
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $scope.items.push({id: counter});
            counter += 10;
        }
       
    };
    $scope.loadMore();
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>AngularJS: Infinite Scrolling </title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
   <script  src="angular-scroll-complete.js"></script>
   
    
    <style type="text/css">
    li {
  height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
#fixed {
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
  </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="scroll" ng-controller="Main">
    <div id="fixed"  when-scrolled="loadMore()" >
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items | orderBy:'id':true ">{{i.id}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    


    
  </body>

</html>
```

hi i am developing scrollbar for skype like application which is loading  the data onscrolling to the top but the scroll bar is not coming down once it touches the top automatically though the next data is loaded successfully.

here is my plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/NobKGyNnpLZHnoHAX824?p=preview

```js
angular.module('angular-scroll-complete', []).directive('whenScrolled', function () {
    return {
        link: {
          pre: function(scope,elem,attr){
              var raw = elem[0];
              var oldscrollHeight=[];
              var scrollTop;
              elem.bind('scroll', function () {
                if (Math.round(raw.scrollTop) ==0) {
              console.log("raw.scrollTop="+Math.round(raw.scrollTop) +" "+ "raw.offsetHeight=="+raw.offsetHeight +" "+"raw.scrollHeight=="+raw.scrollHeight+"oldscrollHeight=="+oldscrollHeight)
              scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
                     
                }
        });
          },
           post: function(scope,elem,attr){
       scope.$watch(function () {
         return elem[0].value;
        }, 
        function (e) {
           elem[0].scrollTop = elem[0].scrollHeight;
        });
    
          }    
        
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>AngularJS: Infinite Scrolling </title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
   <script  src="angular-scroll-complete.js"></script>
   
    
    <style type="text/css">
    li {
  height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
#fixed {
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
  </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="scroll" ng-controller="Main">
    <div id="fixed"  when-scrolled="loadMore()" >
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items | orderBy:'id':true ">{{i.id}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    


    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code snippets throws errors.

Comment: So much code so little problem description

Comment: @Justinas     here is my plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/NobKGyNnpLZHnoHAX824?p=preview could to look into it

Comment: @Alon Eitan i want to the scrollbar to scroll down automatically when data is loaded(on scrolling to the top)here iam hardcoding the value by   raw.scrollTop=raw.scrollHeight/6;   and bringing it down

Comment: @MAWajeed Please include a clear description of the issue in the question by clicking on [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37917424/edit) and i'll remove my downvote

Comment: @MAWajeed No, I will not go to random link to "check code". Provide it in your question and don't advertise your site like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom();
$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
```

Call above method after API returns data. It will scroll to bottom of page or to top of page. [Ref](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/)

Regards